# How can I stop F3 from dimming my display?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using my HP laptop and when I press F3, it just dims the lighting on my computer. I'm really trying to find out how deep I am on Minecraft. Can someone help me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the use of a laptop,  hardly game-specific hardware.

Answer (score 5):

On HP computers, the F-keys are set to the action shown on them by default (which is stupid). If you want to press <kbd>F3</kbd>, you need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

There's a setting in the BIOS to change this, and it's not as scary to change as it sounds. Check out [this article](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02035108&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en) from HP on how to do it. Doing this will make <kbd>F3</kbd> mean <kbd>F3</kbd>, and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> mean "dim screen".

Answer (score 1):

F3 is the standard key for viewing the debug screen which shows your players coordinates. Perhaps your computer has an `fn` key in the bottom left of your keyboard that you need to press with `f3`. If you have the `fn` key press: `fn + f3`

Answer (score -1):

If your graphics card was made by AMD or ATI then the Vari-Bright feature is turned on. To turn it off, go to:

1. AMD Vision Engine Control Center (or AMD Catalyst Control Center)
2. Power
3. PowerPlay
4. Uncheck the "Enable Vari-Bright" option.